# Select SQL Server Server's Alias

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way I can select the alias of a SQL Server?  For example, I have a server on a box that is named `PRODSQL02` but users generally know and connect to this box as `PROD`.

I have been using `@@SERVERNAME` but the end recipients of this information don't always understand that `PRODSQL02` = `PROD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT REPLACE(@@SERVERNAME, 'SQL02','')
```

Which removes the 'SQL02' portion of any servername.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring like this `SELECT SUBSTRING(@@SERVERNAME, 1, 4)` to just get prod out of the value.

Comment: I didn't think of that but unfortunately for Development and Integration, they would contain an extra character.

Comment: I am not sure what that means. Can you give an example?

Comment: The Development server is named `DEVSQL02` and the Integration server is named `INTSQL02` so a 4 character substring would return DEVS or INTS.  I'd like to not have a separate version for the servers, otherwise I'd end up just having it say 'DEV', 'INT', or 'PROD' as appropriate.